# Centralized authentication web2py app and drupal site, is it possible?

Tags: web-services, drupal, web2py

I'm writing a web2py app to manage events and other activities which require users's information, such as id and names for certificates, on the other side there's a drupal site that already has the registered users.

I would like the share the drupal users to my web2py app so i don't have to register users again in my app.

- Already thought in jainrain and tools alike but the info i need is already in the drupal db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To authenticate against the another web server that supports basic authentication is possible using basic auth module. Just add following to your model file after auth initialization and replace a proper http address to your Drupal ...

```
from gluon.contrib.login_methods.basic_auth import basic_auth
auth.settings.login_methods.append(
    basic_auth('https://basic.example.com'))
```

For details see this section from documentation:
[Other login methods and login forms](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09#Other-login-methods-and-login-forms)